# new model index page , shows other model index page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, scaffolding

I have generated new model with :

> rails generate scaffold site

Then I am trying to show all entries , but instead of showing /sites it shows /devices

```
> rake routes
>   test_on GET    /test/on(.:format)                test#on
         test_off GET    /test/off(.:format)               test#off
         power_on GET    /power/on(.:format)               power#on
        power_off GET    /power/off(.:format)              power#off
      power_cycle GET    /power/cycle(.:format)            power#cycle
       home_index GET    /home/index(.:format)             home#index
      devices_new GET    /devices/new(.:format)            devices#new
  devices_destroy DELETE /devices/destroy(.:format)        devices#destroy
    turnon_device PUT    /devices/:id/turnon(.:format)     devices#turnon
   turnoff_device PUT    /devices/:id/turnoff(.:format)    devices#turnoff
powercycle_device PUT    /devices/:id/powercycle(.:format) devices#powercycle
  getsites_device GET    /devices/:id/getsites(.:format)   devices#getsites
          devices GET    /devices(.:format)                devices#index
                  POST   /devices(.:format)                devices#create
       new_device GET    /devices/new(.:format)            devices#new
      edit_device GET    /devices/:id/edit(.:format)       devices#edit
           device GET    /devices/:id(.:format)            devices#show
                  PUT    /devices/:id(.:format)            devices#update
                  DELETE /devices/:id(.:format)            devices#destroy
            users GET    /users(.:format)                  users#index
                  POST   /users(.:format)                  users#create
         new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)              users#new
        edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)         users#edit
             user GET    /users/:id(.:format)              users#show
                  PUT    /users/:id(.:format)              users#update
                  DELETE /users/:id(.:format)              users#destroy
            sites GET    /sites(.:format)                  sites#index
                  POST   /sites(.:format)                  sites#create
         new_site GET    /sites/new(.:format)              sites#new
        edit_site GET    /sites/:id/edit(.:format)         sites#edit
             site GET    /sites/:id(.:format)              sites#show
                  PUT    /sites/:id(.:format)              sites#update
                  DELETE /sites/:id(.:format)              sites#destroy
             root        /                                 devices#index
```

Appreciate any help
Thank you,
D

Comment: I see your `sites` routes listed right there. What is the problem?

Comment: When go to localhost:3000/sites, it comes up as localhost:3000/devices

Answer (score 0):

What you mean? You have both:

```
      devices GET    /devices(.:format)                devices#index
        sites GET    /sites(.:format)                  sites#index
```

Could you write some better explanation about your problem?

Comment: When I go to localhost:3000/sites, it comes up as localhost:3000/devices

Comment: yes and If I go to sites , for some reason it shows only what I put in application.html.erb

Comment: ok, that was not your original question ;) there are many reasons for which the user could be being redirected to devices@index instead of sites#indes, I'll help you with the debug.

Comment: First thing, on the SitesController, on the method index, write on the first line of the method something like 0 / 0 to cause an exception, check the page, if the exception doesn't go though, then its that by some reason your app is not executing the method and perhaps a before_filter is redirecting the user to devices#index, also, if your code doesn't have any proprietary information, you can upload it to github and I'll let you know right away what's the issue. Please, post the content of your ApplicationController, SitesController and DevicesController. Thx

Comment: Hi Rorra, thank you for your help . My problem was that I forgot to add yield to template(application.html.erb) so I could only see template , that was part of de device.html.erb, so when I added it I could see everything I needed. Appreciate your willingness  to help , it is great that here are people who are willing to help , so I am going to my next challenge , dynamic select :)